# instagram username search not match with query

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I am calling instagram's API with this URL

https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q=mtv&count=1&client_id=add38d4ea81e4665962b939c96a929a3&count=1

It's supposed to respond with the username 'mtv' as specified in the q parameter, but the JSON response returns the username 'mtvbrasil'

```
{"meta":{"code":200},"data":[{"username":"mtvbrasil","profile_picture":"https:\/\/instagramimages-a.akamaihd.net\/profiles\/profile_43768325_75sq_1380500869.jpg","id":"43768325","full_name":"MTV Brasil"}]}
```

Comment: I experienced this problem in a scheduled task that ran 15 hours ago (you asked this question 17 hours ago). This scheduled task has been working for months, but it inexplicably found incorrect users this time. I think this was a temporary bug with the Instagram API. It appears to be working now. Your link now returns the correct `mtv` user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instagram's search API does not work as expected! It does not always return the same results as their mobile client returns.

Try adding double quotes to your search term:

[https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q="mtv"&count=1&client_id=add38d4ea81e4665962b939c96a929a3](https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q=%22mtv%22&count=1&client_id=add38d4ea81e4665962b939c96a929a3)

In other cases it might not return *your* best match as the first result, so you might need to not provide a `count` parameter and check all the results for your more desired match.

Answer (score 0):

its odd, not sure why its doing that, but I tried the same API call with `access_token` instead of `client_id` and it returns a lot more results including `mtv`

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q=mtv&access_token=<ACCESS-TOKEN>
```